# Getting IndexOutOfBounds Exception while search for a subtring

Tags: scala

I have a string like

```
var word = "banana"
```

and a sentence like `var sent = "the monkey is holding a banana which is yellow"`

```
sent1 = "banana!!"
```

I want to search banana in `sent` and then write to a file in the following way:

```
the monkey is holding a  
banana    
which is yellow
```

I'm doing it in the following way:

```
var before = sent.substring(0, sent.indexOf(word))
var after = sent.substring(sent.indexOf(word) + word.length)
println(before)
println(after)
```

This works fine but when I do the same for sent1, then it gives me IndexOutOfBoundsException. I think it is because there is nothing before banana in sent1. How to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split based on the word and you will get an array with everything before and after the word.

```
val search = sent.split(word)
search: Array[String] = Array("the monkey is holding a ", " which is yellow")
```

This works in the "banana!!!" case:

```
"banana!!".split(word)
res5: Array[String] = Array("", !!)
```

Now you can write the three lines to a file in your favorite way:

```
println(search(0))
println(word)
println(search(1))
```

Comment: It is giving me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. :O

Comment: He probably meant `search(0)` and `search(1)`

Comment: Yeah, figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What if you had more than one occurrence of the word? `.split` understands regular expressions, so you could improve the previous solution with something like this:

```
string
    .replaceAll("\\s+(?=banana)|(?<=banana)\\s+")
    .foreach(println)
```

`\\s` means a whitespace character
`(?=<word>)` means "followed by `<word>`"
`(?<=<word>)` means "preceded by `<word>`"
So, this would split your string into pieces, using any spaces either preceded or followed by the "banana", and not the word itself. The actual word ends up in the list, just like the other parts of the string, so you don't need to print it out explicitly

This regex trick is called "positive look-around" ( ?= is look-ahead, ?<= is look-behind) in case you are wondering.